# Mobile Push Notifications works only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, mobile-browser

I want to create a Push Notification for my WebApp on mobile Devices (primary Android).

So I started testing:
For now, I do not need a Service Worker, I just want to send a push notification when a user opens the page.

This is what I'm testing for the last hours and days but somehow the notifications works only on Firefox Mobile. On a desktop browser, it works on every browser I tested.
Every mobile browser asks me for notification-permissions but it does not make any single notification. Notifications are allowed on all of mine mobile browsers.

I tried the pushjs.org framework and I wrote a Code with the Notification API. I'm strugeling and really need some help.

Here is my code:

**Version A with Notification API**

```
function notifyMe() {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
  }
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    notify();
  }
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        notify();
      }
    });
  }
  function notify() {
    var notification = new Notification('Push Benachrichtigung Test', {
      icon: 'images/icon.png',
      body: "Hallo, das ist ein Test.",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("https://www.google.com/");      
    };
    //setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 7000); 
  }


}

notifyMe();
```

**Version B with Pushjs.org Framwork**

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase-app.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase-messaging.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='js/push.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='js/main.js' type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>

function demo() {
    Push.create('Hello wooorld!', {
        body: 'How\'s it hangin\'?',
        icon: '/images/icon.png',
        link: '/#',
        timeout: 4000,
        onClick: function () {
            console.log("Fired!");
            window.focus();
            this.close();
        },
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
    });
}

demo();

</script>
```

Comment: You should check the browser compatibility for the API https://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications

Comment: Thanks @KingGary, I was at least 10 time on the caniuse site but didn't recognize that chrome mobile needs a service worker... damn it. thanks!

Comment: I can not find that on the desktop, the notification on any website is not poping